# pythonic way to add elements to nested list

Tags: python

I have a nest list:

```
listSchedule = [[list1], [list2], etc..]]
```

I have another list and I want to append to each nested list the element of this list if the first element of each matches a string.

I can do it but I wonder if there is a more 'pythonic' way, using list comprehension?

```
index = 0;
for row in listSchedule:
   if row[0] == 'Download':
      row[3] = myOtherList[index]
      index +=1
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a `dict` (or if `Download` might appear multiple times, a multi-`dict` like `collections.defaultdict(list)`) or something? Needing to loop over every element to find a "header" to append data to sounds an awful lot like the case where you'd want a `dict`.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I suspect [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). Can you provide more details about the problem so we're not just applying touch-ups to a bad design? Even a real [MCVE] would be helpful (as written, this code guarantees an `IndexError`, since it assigns to `row[3]`, but the `listSchedule` you provided is a `list` of len 1 `list`s, so any index but `row[0]` would error out.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is very readable, I would not change it.

With a list comprehension you could write something like:

```py
for index, row in enumerate([row for row in listSchedule if row[0] == 'Download']):
    row[3] = myOtherList[index]
```

Comment: Omit the brackets; no need for a temporary `list` here (`enumerate` is perfectly happy to work with generators, it doesn't need full sequences). Without the brackets, `enumerate(row for row in listSchedule if row[0] == 'Download')` enumerates a generator expression that produces the rows lazily, no potentially large temporary `list`s needed.

Answer (score 1):

you could try that but make a copy of the otherlist to not lose the info:

```
[row+[myotherlist.pop(0)] if row[0]=='Download' else row for row in listScheduel]
```

for example:

```
list = [['Download',1,2,3],[0,1,2,3],['Download',1,2,3],['Download',1,2,3]]
otherlist = [0,1,2,3,4]
l = [ row+[otherlist.pop(0)] if row[0]=='Download' else row for row in list]
```

Output:

```
[['Download', 1, 2, 3, 0],
[0, 1, 2, 3],
['Download', 1, 2, 3, 1],
['Download', 1, 2, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truly `append`, why not use `row.append(myOtherList[index])`? That way you avoid `IndexErrors`

```
i = 0

for row in listSchedule:
    if row[0]=="Download":
        row.append(myOtherList[i])
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a queue and pop its values one by one when we meet the condition. To avoid copying of data let's implement the queue as a view over `myOtherList` using an iterator (thanks to [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger)).

```
queue = iter(myOtherList)

for row in listSchedule:
    if row[0] == "Download":
        row.append(next(iter))
```

Comment: You could save the temporary `deque` with just `queue = iter(myOtherList)`, and `row.append(next(queue))`. Assumes `myOtherList` isn't being otherwise modified in the loop, but otherwise gets the same behavior, with no overhead.